# Open Source SE Software | Chance for the Community to Contribute to SE Software

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

SO/SE is now well established hence there is no possibility of competition as long as one keeps the good work.

Also, there are more than a few thousand community feature requests which is not yet implemented. Maybe it would be great to give the community a chance to contribute to the software by making it open source under a permissive license.

This will reduce the burden of the internal development team and also get more community participation in the implementation of features. If the community wants a feature badly then there is a chance it will get contributed.

SO/SE can ensure what is contributed is of high quality.

Comment: I agree, but it'll probably never happen.

Comment: I'd rather not risk the stability of the entire platform just to have some random people implement some arbitrary obscure feature-requests. Considering the amount of users SO has I would also fully expect that leading to the development team spending most of their time reviewing merge candidates or rejecting PRs that try to "fix" the voting system. I used to think this would be a good idea but after lurking on meta for a couple of years I am positively sure it isn't :)

Comment: There are open source clones of SO/SE. Contribute to one of them if you want to. Maybe if their functionality outshines SO/SE you'll persuade everyone to move there or if not it might encourage SO/SE developers to implement new features here to keep up.

Comment: @RobertLongson SO is too big and well established to convince anyone to move to another platform.

Comment: @ivarni the idea behind open-source in that case would be reaching community consensus on which feature requests to include, not letting everyone pick a random feature request and implement it.

Comment: Every contribution need not be merged.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena AOL, MySpace, Pets.com, Friends Reunited etc, etc.

Comment: @RobertLongson all of those ended up shutting down, and several better alternatives emerged before that. The communities rarely survive in the same form.

Comment: @zoe The point is that history shows us that nobody is too big and well established to be assured of eternal dominance.

Comment: @RobertLongson as long as SO is better it will do well. The community gets a chance to make it even better than what they can do themselves due to HR bandwidth.

Answer (score 16):

> Maybe it would be great to give the community a chance to contribute
>   to the software by making it open source under a permissive license.

This would probably be a nice thing for the community, but Stack Exchange is a for-profit company and they will not enable anyone with a plan and an idea to flat out copy their service and replace them.

They also sell access to a private copy of the software via teams and enterprise, and making it open source would allow anyone trivially to use it without paying.

I get the sentiment, but you can't expect a company to just give away its prime asset to everyone for free.

Comment: Building a community is hard. So even if one runs a copy it will be very nitch and small.

Comment: right. But they're selling access to the very software you propose making open source with a permissive license (just access, not really support), for up to 17$/user/month. You can't in realistic terms ask them to just start giving that for free instead.

Comment: Running a clone of many organisations would be too expensive other than for very large ones with many users. The large organisations will be willing to pay. There are FOSS software which also makes money.

Comment: Also, open-sourcing will be a test of faith on SO Software and Model.

Comment: @Suminda you can explain to Magisch why opensourcing a web application can be a great idea, but Magisch is defending why it's **not** a good idea, from the viewpoint of the Stack Overflow company. Out of self-preservation, the company will always try to do what is good for itself. Do you understand that? So you can list all benefits of open source to Magisch, but that isn't going to make Stack Overflow the company go _"Well you know what, Suminda makes some great points, here's our source code"_.

Comment: While forks may exist in an attempt to replace the original SO, is there *really* that much of a difference? All the content on SO is already available in a CC-By-SA 3.0 data dump - someone could re-write a similar system from scratch (which [has already happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953/332043)), and add all the content to the new site with proper attribution for existing content. The only thing that happens by not open-sourcing is that the open-source developers will not and cannot add any features to the original site.

Comment: Provided enough traction, replacing SE is possible, whether SE is open-source or not.

Comment: @Zoe right. But SE will not make a move that makes it so basically all that seperates a company from getting teams/enterprise for free is a IT department that knows how to run the software on their own server.

Comment: @CodeCaster Open-sourcing means you can receive a code contribution from the community. This can be peer and SO/SE validated. This is the main reason.

Comment: @Zoe I don't believe with the current site of SO it can be replaced.

Comment: @Suminda yes, that is one reason why it might be beneficial to open source the Stack Overflow software. It also ignores all reasons why it may *not* be beneficial.

Comment: @Magisch if someone wants to run it for free they can use a free clone. People who pay are the ones who want the real SO. So I don't think this will be affected. Given the size of SO programming community SO can easily get 100x more contributions for features and bug fixes through the community, hence cost saving. The community also wins as they get a say in the direction of the software.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena your whole argument based on assumption that speed of writing code for a feature is what prevents new features being implemented in the SE engine/SO site... I seriously doubt that - clarifying why decreasing/removing dev cost will make overall feature cost significantly lower (either in general or for SO in particular) could made your question more plausible... (Also I don't think it would have changed official outcome of "declined")